# Lua: Coloring "Win" status fails

Tags: if-statement, lua

I've had this function for almost two years now, and I can't seem to figure out why it's not working for colorizing. Here's the entire function, but you'll see the core parts that aren't working below.

```
function showscoreboard()
    local function len(arg)
            return string.len(arg)
    end

    local function tbuff(arg)
            if len(arg) < 3 then
                    return arg.." "
            else
                    return arg
            end
    end

    local function sbuff(arg)
            if len(arg) < 2 then
                    return " "..arg
            else
                    return arg
            end
    end

    local function cteam(t,s)
                    local status = s or nil
                    local forecolor = ""

                    if status == "p" then
                            forecolor = "yellow"
                    elseif status == "w" then
                            forecolor = "cyan"
                    else
                            forecolor = "limegreen"
                    end

                    return "<color fore="..forecolor..">"..t.."</color>"
            end

    local function bcolor(i)
            local i = i or 0

            if i%2 == 1 then
                    return "maroon"
            else
                    return "navy"
            end
    end

    local scorestring = ""
    local allteams = {["ATL"]=0,["WAS"]=0,["MIA"]=0,["CLE"]=0,["OAK"]=0,["SD"]=0,["IND"]=0,["NYJ"]=0,["TEN"]=0,["SEA"]=0,["PHI"]=0,["DEN"]=0,["GB"]=0,["BUF"]=0,["TB"]=0,["PIT"]=0,["MIN"]=0,["HOU"]=0,["DET"]=0,["TB"]=0,["CAR"]=0,["CHI"]=0,["STL"]=0,["NYG"]=0,["ARI"]=0,["NO"]=0,["KC"]=0,["SF"]=0,["NE"]=0}
    local byeweek = ""

    for _,v in ipairs(nflscores.ss) do
            allteams[v[5]] = 1
            allteams[v[7]] = 1
    end

    for i,v in pairs(allteams) do
            if v == 0 then
                    byeweek = byeweek .. "<color white>".. i .."</color>\r"
            end
    end

    for i,v in ipairs(nflscores.ss) do
            local hteam = v[7]
            local ateam = v[5]
            local qgame = v[3]
            local hscre = v[8] or 0
            local ascre = v[6] or 0
            if v[4] then
                    qtime = "<color white>Time: "..v[4].."</color>"
            else
                    qtime = ""
            end
            local gposs = v[9] or ""
            if gposs ~= "" then
                    if gposs == hteam then
                            hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam),"p")
                            ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam))
                    else
                            ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam),"p")
                            hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam))
                    end
            else
                    hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam))
                    ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam))
            end
            if qgame == "Final" or qgame == "final overtime" then
                    if hscre > ascre then
                            hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam),"w")
                            ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam))
                    elseif hscre < ascre then
                            ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam),"w")
                            hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam))
                    else
                            ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam))
                            hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam))
                    end
                    if qgame == "Final" then
                            qgame = "<color cyan>F</color>"
                            elseif qgame == "final overtime" then
                                    qgame = "<color cyan>F/OT</color>"
                    end
            elseif qgame == "Pregame" then
                    qgame = "<color cyan>Pre</color>"
            elseif qgame == "Halftime" then
                    qgame = "<color white>"..qgame.."</color>"
            else
                    qgame = "<color white>Q"..qgame.."</color>"
            end
            scorestring = scorestring .. "<color back="..bcolor(i) .. ">".. v[1] .. ": " .. ateam .. "<color white>: " .. sbuff(ascre) .. "</color> <color black>@</color> " .. hteam .. "<color white>: ".. sbuff(hscre) .."</color></color> " .. qgame .. " " .. qtime .. "\r"
    end
    return scorestring .. "<color white>Bye week:</color>\r"..byeweek
end
```

The part that isn't working properly is:

```
 if hscre > ascre then
                            hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam),"w")
                            ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam))
                    elseif hscre < ascre then
                            ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam),"w")
                            hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam))
                    else
                            ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam))
                            hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam))
                    end
```

The function for cteam is:

```
local function cteam(t,s)
                    local status = s or nil
                    local forecolor = ""

                    if status == "p" then
                            forecolor = "yellow"
                    elseif status == "w" then
                            forecolor = "cyan"
                    else
                            forecolor = "limegreen"
                    end

                    return "<color fore="..forecolor..">"..t.."</color>"
            end
```

Now, it colors the "p" status just fine. But when the status changes to "w", it fails, and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why. Am I missing something? Could this code be a lot cleaner?

**Edit**: I haven't found the issue to the problem, but apparently the "elseif status == "w" statement is completely bypassed. When the games are being played, the correct team in possession shows yellow. However, after the game is over, both teams are lime green, as if no score was higher than the other.

**2nd Edit**: The error listed in the first answer has been corrected. Still, it doesn't solve the issue. I'm still quite at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing jumps out and I can't test here but here are some things to check:

You mention that cteam works correctly during the game, and that it's only once the game is over that cteam doesn't give the correct final result. So the logic of cteam is correct. The problem must be in the code that calls cteam: does cteam ever get called with s equals "w": this would never happen if hscre and ascre are always the same. Also there is a typo in the branch code that calls cteam:

```
if hscre > ascre then
    hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam),"w")
    ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam))
elseif hscre < ascre then
    ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam,"w")) -- ERR
    hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam))
else
    ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam))
    hteam = cteam(tbuff(hteam))
end
```

The line that is tagged ERR should be:

```
ateam = cteam(tbuff(ateam),"w")
```

About cleaning up the code: post your question on StackOverflow's code review forum.

Comment: Edited question to address a bit of testing. The scores are (generally) always different, so "w" should get called every time. Changing the order of testing did nothing as well.

Comment: Good catch on the error! But... still, it never seems to get called. I'm not sure why because the scores are almost never the same.